# Storing Hashes to Password in PHP

Tags: php, database, security, password-hash, php-password-hash

I am new to hashes password storage. Can someone point of what I might be doing wrong. I'm using specially PHP, not C or any deviation of C.

Storing Hash:

1. Receive password
2. Send it to [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function with an algorithm like `sha-512`, and a cost factor.
3. Little stuck here. When iterating do I use the received password hash?
4. Length it with `pbkdf2` key deviation function.
5. Store in database.

Retrieving Hash:

1. Get user's attempt at password.
2. Stuck here also but I assume you use the `password_verify` function.
3. If a match validate other deny.

If someone could post a correct solution that would be much obliged.

Comment: Can you please post the code. Then others could be easily understand your problem.

Comment: $password = $_POST['password']; $hash = password_hash(7, 12, $password); $i = 0; while $i < 12800) { $hash = password_hash(7, 12, $hash); } Not sure how to implement the hash_pbkdf2 function.

Answer (score 2):

Why bother with while() loops if you can just use the build-in options?

```
$password = $_POST['password'];
$hash = password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT, array('cost' => 12));
echo $hash;
```

This is the correct way to do it. And to verify the password all you have to do is the following.

```
if(password_verify($password, $hash)){
    //valid password
}
```

Comment: I don't see the built in loop in the password_hash function. Which parameter is it?

Comment: Cost is a exponential option. 2^11 is the default if I remember correctly which is more than enough iterations right now. Which takes ~100ms