# CakePhp password hash in raw php

Tags: php, cakephp, freeradius, radius

Now I'm writing script for self sign in and forgot password page in Radiusdesk.
when I'm writing script for forgot password page I need replace a hashed password created by cake php. but I'm not using cake php in my script.

My Question is how to create hased password in raw php as same created by cakephp.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Storing Hashes to Password in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34470955/storing-hashes-to-password-in-php)

Comment: A quick search of the source shows this: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/4.x/src/Auth/DefaultPasswordHasher.php